# Object is acting as a mask

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, masking

I have an object in my scene which is acting as a mask, but i need it to be just a regular object. Here's a gif:
[image]

It's not just the render view but it also renders in the final image as a mask. This does not happen in eevee, though. Both of the objects have a Principled BSDF material and the object which is acting as a mask DOES NOT have a holdout shader. I also tried going through some of the options in the object properties, but nothing changed.

Here's the blend file:

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Just to make sure - isn't holdout enabled in *Object tab > Visibility*?

Comment: No, it wasn't, it's probably something else. I also added the blend file now. @JachymMichal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]You have it as "Shadow Catcher" you need to select the object and go to Object properties > Visibility > Shadow Catcher (uncheck this one)

Comment: Thanks! It finally works now :)

Comment: @daniela shadow catcher is not meant for the object to have shadows, but to create an object that is invisible except for the shadows projected by other objects. Shadow catcher is used mostly when you want to composite on top of images.